# Save Printed Text in Previous Cell Independent of Print Command

Tags: python

I'm using a package-specific command which prints out different values (see code below). The package that I'm using doesn't have a command to save the resulting printed text as a dictionary, array, list, etc., and when I've tried to print it out or save it in the usual ways, the package (pyCloudy) breaks down. My question is this: Is there a way to take a printed result (printed NOT using the normal print() command) and save it as an array, dictionary, list, etc.? Basically some function that looks to the printed text in the above cell, doesn't care how that text was printed, and saves it as an array, dictionary, list, etc.?

````
S__4_105076M 8.066621e-09
NE_2_128101M 1.422510e-08
S__3_187078M 7.536069e-09
FE_3_229190M 1.693226e-09
FE_3_330270M 5.151949e-10
S__3_334704M 7.499141e-10
NE_3_360036M 6.078342e-11```
````

Comment: I think it's this function you're talking about? https://github.com/Morisset/pyCloudy/blob/de78e89bc15dafef87a42acf65938226dc35589b/pyCloudy/c1d/cloudy_model.py#L1924 It mostly just calls some methods and prints the return value; the print function itself doesn't do a lot. You should be able to get your data as data by calling those same methods the print method does. Don't attempt complicated workarounds like trying to parse output back into arrays.

Comment: Yes, that's the function I'm talking about. Thank you so much for your response, re-framing this question really helped!